# Subtracting a Series from a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, series, subtraction

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3), columns=['a','b','c'], index=['car','bike','cycle'])
print(df2)

       a  b  c
car    0  1  2
bike   3  4  5
cycle  6  7  8

ser_c= df2.loc['car']
print(ser_c)

a    0
b    1
c    2
Name: car, dtype: int32

df2 - ser_c

        a   b   c
car     0   0   0
bike    3   3   3
cycle   6   6   6
```

I created a dataframe 'df2' and extracted the index 'car' row and transformed it into a series "ser_c".

I then took the difference between df2 and ser_c and the respective values in 'bike' and 'cycle' indexes were also being subtracted acccordingly (i.e 0 1 2).

My question is: Why does the subtraction also apply to both 'bike' and 'cycle' indexes ? I thought it should only apply to 'car' index since "ser_c" was from .loc['car'] ?

Comment: The series (plural) are the columns, `a, b, c`, nor the rows, `car, bike, cycle`. You're subtracting a dataframe with 3 series from another dataframe with 3 series

Comment: It is a broadcasting behavior of *pandas*. [Broadcasting behavior](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior)